# jersey client get error message body

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-client

I am using the following code to consume a rest post service

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("wrong url");
Invocation.Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = builder.post(Entity.entity(param, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);
```

As expected I am getting error. and status code `400 Bad Request`. But i am not getting the error message. when i run `response.getStatusInfo()` i get bad request but my server sends additional info.

when i call this using `postman` i get error info in the Body window.

So how do I get this error body info from the response object?
or any other way???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the response body as usual with [Response#readEntity](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-):

> Read the message entity input stream as an instance of specified Java type using a `MessageBodyReader` that supports mapping the message entity stream onto the requested type.

Example:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("wrong url");
Invocation.Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = builder.post(Entity.entity(param, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);
String body = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

With [Response#getStatusInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getStatusInfo--) you get only HTTP [status](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.StatusType.html#getStatusCode--), [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.StatusType.html#getFamily--) and [reason phrase](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.StatusType.html#getReasonPhrase--).

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Jersey and JAX-RS, but I believe this question is equivalent to [*Handling custom error response in JAX-RS 2.0 client library*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561527/handling-custom-error-response-in-jax-rs-2-0-client-library), which has much better answers.